# using environment variables in excel

Tags: vba, excel, batch-file

So  I am using this code in excel to read environment parameters on startup:

```
Dim ExcelArgs As String
Dim arg As String
ExcelArgs = Environ("ExcelArgs")

MsgBox ExcelArgs
If InStr(UCase(ExcelArgs), "CREO") >= 0 Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Len(ExcelArgs) > Len("CREO") Then
        arg = Split(ExcelArgs, ",")(1)
        Call Creo.addNewPartToPartslist(arg)
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
```

and this line in my batch script:

```
echo "Launch excel"

Set "ExcelArgs=CREO,DXFWITHOUTDRW

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE16\Excel.exe" /r "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB" 

exit 0
```

The problem is that if i run the batch file once, keep excel open change the  excelargs to CREO,wqhatever in batch file and rerun batch file the excelargs, dos not get updated!!!

So my theory is that excel either caches out the environment variable or that if it is being used by one instance the batch script can not set it

link with some info about passing arguments to excel:
https://superuser.com/questions/640359/bat-file-to-open-excel-with-parameters-spaces

Comment: If you copied your code in hier from the batch-file, let me tell you there is a double-quote missing after your `set` -instruction. With that a lot of things will be seen as strings which they are not supposed to be and strings are not seen as they should be.

Comment: This almost certainly has to do with the scope of environment variables in batch files.  [This question](http://superuser.com/questions/340729/variable-scope-in-batch-files) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Just looking at your overall design for a solution, and I'm wondering why you're passing arguments individually. Could you possibly send a full list of comma-delimited items exactly once, working with all of them in the `Split` array? Or is this example simplified/contrived to exemplify the problem, so your overarching design depends on this sort of behavior and such a workaround is impossible?

Comment: Can you try `....\excel.exe /x /r ".....`?

Answer (score 3):

Usually excel sees if there is a previous instance running and let this instance handle the file opening.

Is this important? Yes, in your case both requests to open the file are handled by the same excel process.

How does it make a difference? Environment variables are not shared. Each process has it own environment block that is initialized when the process is created (can be a customized block or a copy of the environment of the parent process) and once the environment is created for a process, only this process can change its environment.

In your case, when you start `excel` the new process gets a copy of the environment block of the `cmd` process. Later, when you change the `cmd` environment, the already running `excel` instance sees no changes in environment and, as the new request to open excel is converted to a request to the previous process, there is not a new process with a new copy of the `cmd` environment with the changes.

The only way I see to make it work is to force excel to start a new process (that will inherit the changes in the `cmd` instance) instead of reusing the previous one.

But this depends on the `excel` version. As far as I know, the 2013 version includes an `/x` switch to force separate process usage. For previous versions, maybe [this question](https://superuser.com/q/431061/362853), or [this one](https://superuser.com/q/21602/362853) could help you.

Comment: So the shift /x works! However if I already have personal.xlsb open(i.e an instance of excel running) then I get up this questionbox if I would like to cancel or open as read only, is there a switch i can use to avoid that? /x /r does not work for some reason:( Is the order of switches important?

Comment: @skatun, I've tested with `.xlsx` and `.xlsb` files, in local and network drives, `/x /r` and `/r /x`, with the file closed, or already opened in write or read only. For me, the second request to open the file in a separate process in read only mode works in all cases. I can not reproduce your problem.

Comment: @skatun, sorry, may be I didn't explain it correctly. I know what your error is (as probably anyone working with excel in a networked environment). But I can not reproduce your problem. As I have indicated I have tested all combinations in my environment and I can not make it fail. For me it works.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is open
[image: Excel is open]

Then i start the batch script:

[image: batch start]

The it does not open it as read only by default, but prompt me instead, not a big issue but a bit annoying, and it also make it impossible to loop through to run the batch several times for different input parameters.

[image]

A bit unsure how I should post this, couldnt paste images in comments, and to edit the the original question, which was how to start excel with enviroment variable in new instance (/x did the trick), but now /r does not work, Should I post as new question and refer to this one or can I leave it as an answer?